# RestSharp returns BadRequest error But PostMan works correctly

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

I have this piece of code to upload a file to a server:

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8888/add");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddFile("image", "E:/1.jpg");
request.AddParameter("filepath", "images_store/1");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

This code is generated by Postman itself but when I run it in my app it give BadRequest

[image]

Whats wrong?

Comment: Don't know if this is an issue, but your header type is different.  Code "x-www-form-urlencoded" Postman ""form-data".  Postman also has more headers set (10) than you do in code.  Check these.

Answer (score 0):

I see in postman you selected form-data as ContentType, but in code it says x-www-form-urlencoded.

Habe you tried changing that?

Comment: I changed it, again BadRequest. However the generated code is which I wrote above

Comment: Can you share how the controller part looks?

Comment: Sorrily the used api is third party